# Programmatic initialization of a long array at compile or initialization time

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

Here is a code snippet illustrating my question:

```
const float D    = 0.1F;
const float A[4] = {sin(0*D), sin(1*D), sin(2*D), sin(3*D)};
```

Imagine that global array `A` is much longer and you don't want to do all of this repetitive typing. Is there a shorter way to initialize array A at compile or initialization time, i.e. without having to write initialization function and call it somewhere in my program?

Comment: The initialization you've shown doesn't occur at static initialization time, but at dynamic initialization time - that is, at run time. `sin` is not `constexpr`. The code snippet doesn't appear to actually illustrate your question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You are right, I will edit my question.

Comment: Is this for a lookup table? Simply performing the calculation can be faster than looking up the value on modern CPUs.

Comment: @NeilKirk It is a lookup table, but computing trigonometric functions is still much slower then getting them from a small lookup table on modern CPU.

Comment: How do you know, did you measure in a real application? A simple benchmark cannot be used as it won't model the cache usage of the real program. Lookup tables use cache space.

Comment: @NeilKirk _Lookup tables use cache space_ - note that I wrote _small lookup table_, in my case 16 or 32 elements, so cache impact is negligible. As far as CPU throughput for trigonometric functions see [Agner](http://www.agner.org/optimize/): FSIN takes about 100 micro-ops to execute vs. a few for accessing lookup table on Haswell CPU.

Comment: Your lookup table is going to be less accurate than calling the native function. If you have different values of D, each will need its own lookup table, taking up more space. Unless you have profiled your program and determined the trig functions are the bottleneck, I would advise against this premature optimization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could initialize A during dynamic initialization time as follows:

```
const float *init_a(float x_)
{
  static float data[4];
  for(unsigned i=0; i<4; ++i)
    data[i]=sin(i*x_);
  return data;
}

const float D=0.1f;
const float *A=init_a(D);
```

Comment: Thanks, it does what I asked for and it is easier to read than template based solutions. I just hoped that there is something looking more C++17 and beyond rather than plain old C...

Answer (score 4):

You may use code generator to generate initialization code. That is, write program that will write your initialization code for you. You may actually calculate values at generation-time.

Remember that C++ allows placing `,` after last element. It's also isn't necessary to specify array size. These two things should ease writing of generator.

This simple python code should work well:

```
from math import sin

print('const float A[', N, '] = {')
for i in range(N):
    print('\t', sin(i*D), ',', sep='')
print('};')
```

Comment: I often specify array length so I don't have to count when I reread the code - with a little bit longer ones it is not obvious what the length is. If I only could use Python or similar language inside C++ code for meta-programming...

Comment: It's better to configure your build scripts to generate source code automatically every time generator source code is changed. In that way generating will be automated causing almost none time overhead.

Comment: It's easy for generator to print array size. I've changed answer to reflect that

Answer (score 4):

Ok I just realized this doesn't actually answer the question, because it specifies "without having to write initialization function and call it somewhere in my program?" But I can't think of a convenient alternative.

```
template<size_t N>
std::array<float, N> GetLookupTable(float d)
{
    std::array<float, N> table;
    // .. populate table here
    return table;
}

// a global somewhere
(static?) const auto Table_10x5 = GetLookupTable<10>(5.0f);
```

Comment: It actually does answer my question. Your solution uses initialization function (as JarkkoL's did), but I don't have to call it in my program - it is done automagically during initialization stage.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Be aware not to put the line defining the array in a header file, or you could get multiple copies in your program.

Answer (score 4):

This first part is obsolete in C++14, but not long:

```
template<unsigned...>struct indexes { using type=indexes; };
template<unsigned Max, unsigned...Is>struct make_indexes:make_indexes<Max-1,Max-1,Is...>{};
template<unsigned...Is>struct make_indexes<0,Is...>:indexes<Is...>{};
template<unsigned Max>using make_indexes_t=typename make_indexes<Max>::type;
```

this is some template meta programming that lets us create and pass around bundles of indexes.

Then some code to generate the array:

```
namespace details {
  template<std::size_t N, unsigned...Is>
  std::array<float, N> poly_sin(float src, indexes<Is...>) {
    return { (Is*sin(src))... };
  }
}

template<std::size_t N>
std::array<float, N> poly_sin(float src) {
  return details::poly_sin<N>( src, make_indexes_t<N>{} );
}
```

The first method takes `indexes<Is...>` and we plan that `Is...` is `0, 1, 2, ..., N-1`.  It then expands the parameter pack into a `std::array` of the right size.

`make_indexes_t<N>{}` expands (at compile time) to `indexes<0, 1, 2, ..., N-1>{}`, which is then passed to `details::poly_sin`, which then can deduce the `Is...` and use them within itself.

And point of use:

```
const float D    = 0.1F;
const auto A = poly_sin<4>(D);
```

if you had a `constexpr` `sin` function, you could even make `poly_sin` a `constexpr` function and have it basically guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time.

If this is the case, make `D` `constexpr` and same with the two `poly_sin` functions.

As written, this occurs at dynamic initialization time.

While it appears that the array is copied twice, RVO elision means that any decent compiler will directly construct it in `A`.

If you want to be able to do this in general, first start with the above `indexes` code.  Then add this:

```
template<class Sig>using result_of_t=typename std::result_of<Sig>::type;
namespace details {
  template<std::size_t N, class F, unsigned... Is>
  std::array< result_of_t< F(unsigned) >, N >
  make_array( F&& f, indexes<Is...> ) {
    return { f( Is )... };
  }
}
template<std::size_t N, class F>
std::array< result_of_t< F(unsigned) >, N >
make_array( F&& f ) {
  return details::make_array( std::forward<F>(f), make_indexes_t<N>{} );
}

const auto A = make_array<4>( [](unsigned i){ return float(i*sin(D)); } );
```

which uses a lambda to pass in the code that is repeated to build the array.  Sadly, lambdas are not by default `constexpr` so you cannot do it at compile time.

Comment: This is the most concise template based solution in C++14 (I'm assuming that the first part of code completely disappears in C++14).

Comment: @PaulJurczak The indexes stuff gets replaced with C++14 integral sequences yes.  Note that at ~1000 entries the `indexes` code above is insufficiently slick, but the integral sequences is (and you can make the above `indexes` more slick if you need 1000+ entries).  But in C++11 it is 4 lines if you only need 100s of entries.  It hits ... significantly more if you need 1000s.

Answer (score 3):

You could either use [boost.preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) and in particular the `BOOST_PP_ENUM` macro, like the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum.hpp>

#define SIZE 4
#define D    0.1
#define ORDER(z, n, text) std::sin(n * D)

double const A[SIZE] = { BOOST_PP_ENUM(SIZE, ORDER, ~) };

int main() {
  for(auto i : A) std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Or, you could use `std::array` instead of raw arrays, and via use of template meta-programming to generate a `std::array` at compile time. like the example below:

```
template<typename T, typename F, int SIZE, int... N> 
constexpr std::array<T, SIZE> 
genarray(F f) { 
  return std::array<T, SIZE>{{ f(N)... }};
}

template<typename T, typename F, int SIZE, int...> struct recursive_gen;

template<typename T, typename F, int SIZE, int... Args> 
struct recursive_gen<T, F, SIZE, 0, Args...> { 
  static constexpr std::array<T, SIZE> generate(F f) {
    return genarray<T, F, SIZE, 0, Args...>(f);
  }
};

template<typename T, typename F, int SIZE, int N, int... Args> 
struct recursive_gen<T, F, SIZE, N, Args...> {
  static constexpr std::array<T, SIZE> generate(F f) {
    return recursive_gen<T, F, SIZE, N - 1, N, Args...>::generate(f); 
  } 
};

template<typename T, int SIZE>
struct array_generator {
  template<typename F>
  static constexpr std::array<T, SIZE> generate(F f) {
    return recursive_gen<T, F, SIZE, SIZE - 1>::generate(f);
  }
};

std::array<double, 4> const A = array_generator<double, 4>::generate([](int i) { return std::sin(0.1 * i);});
std::array<double, 4> const B = array_generator<double, 4>::generate([](int i) { return std::cos(0.1 * i);});

constexpr int fun(int i) { return 2 * i; } 
constexpr std::array<int, 4> const C = array_generator<int, 4>::generate(fun); // generation during compile time
```

### [**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1951206cfbd6dd2)

Note however, that in order for generation to take place at compile time input function in `array_generator` must be `constexpr`. This is not the case for trigonometric functions (i.e., they are not `constexpr`). Thus initialization of `array`s `A` and `B` will take place at initialization time, whereas generation of `array C` will take place at compile time.

Comment: JarkkoL's answer could be tidied up a bit, but what advantage does your approach have over his? Are compilers able to evaluate `std::sin` at compile-time?

Comment: @NeilKirk you are right `std::sin` will not be evaluated at compile time. IMHO though, my solution has several advantages over the one you mentioned. First off, what would happen if user wanted to create two or more arrays with different `D` values? Second it decays the array to a pointer and size information is lost.

Comment: JarkkoL's answer can be tidied up to provide those advantages by passing D as a template parameter to the function, and returning the array by reference.

Comment: Hm you can't pass floats as template value parameters.

Comment: @NeilKirk Indeed you can't *14.3.2/1 Template non-type arguments      [temp.arg.nontype]* ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Imagine that global array A is much longer and you don't want to do all of this repetitive typing. Is there a shorter way to initialize array A at compile or initialization time

Create a generator and pass it through `std::generate_n()` (or plain `std::generate()`).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>

template <typename Value_t>
struct SinGenerator{
    SinGenerator(std::size_t start = 0, Value_t counter_scalar = 1)
        : index{start},
          scalar{counter_scalar} {
    }

    Value_t operator()() {
        return sin(index++ * scalar);
    }

    std::size_t index;
    Value_t scalar;
};

template <typename Value_t, std::size_t Size>
std::array<Value_t, Size> init_table(const std::size_t start, 
                                     const Value_t counter_scalar) {
    std::array<Value_t, Size> arr;
    SinGenerator<Value_t> gen(start, counter_scalar);
    std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), gen);
    return arr;
}

const auto kSinTable(init_table<float, 10>(0, 0.1f));
```

Comment: Your solution requires _write initialization function and call it somewhere in my program_, which I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

In case you `A` array will always stays the same and is very big, you can always write a short script, which calculates every value in array and output could be used in source code to have static initialization.

In case formula is simple, even MS Excel could be used to *generate* that kind of static initialization data.